# Using a H1 logo in HTML5

Tags: html, seo, html-heading

The "h1 tag with an image" debate seems as old as time itself, but with [HTML5 explicitly allowing multiple H1 tags as part of its spec](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824), all the previous questions on this subject seem out of date.

As I understand it, the following works perfectly with the [HTML OA](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/):

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      <a href="http://www.example.com"> 
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Ernie's Restaurant - Great Italian food">
      </a>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <nav><!-- the site-wide navigation --></nav> 

  <article>
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <p>…</p>
  </article>

</body>
```

But I'm working with an SEO company on a website and they've told me:

> "The logo link CAN’T be H1. It doesn’t make sense."

Are they right? Is there something bad about the above document outline? If you can't put the logo in a H1 tag, why do [the W3C do it themselves on their website](http://www.w3.org/)?

These people are supposedly SEO experts, but I just don't understand their complaint. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, you'd want to wrap the image in an anchor, which also has a title... See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130834/seo-images-and-and-h1) and [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665037/replacing-h1-text-with-a-logo-image-best-method-for-seo-and-accessibility).

Maybe they were just nervous about the lack of a proper anchor? The img tag is entirely legitimate.

Comment: Doh. Well spotted. There IS a `<a>` tag on the actual website. I just forgot to include it. There isn't a `title=` attribute, so maybe that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have an `img` element as content of an `h1` element.
Yes, it makes sense to have the `img`-logo as `h1` (in case it belongs to the `body` sectioning root, like it does in your example).

If your site doesn’t show a separate textual name, you definitely should do this. Otherwise, the document outline could be wrong (if you don’t use sectioning elements wherever needed) or at least the outline would have an unlabeled top-level entry, which is not very user friendly/accessible.

If you have a site logo *and* a textual site name, it’s discussible: either include the `img` together with the text in the same `h1`, or have only one of these elements in `h1` (either one is possible) and have the other one as "[alternative title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451639/1591669)", e.g., together in a `header` element.

For examples, see some of my related answers on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920215/1591669), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915502/1591669), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860905/1591669)) and Code Review ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40262/16414), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/28295/16414), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45517/16414)).

(Your "SEO expert" is not the only one having a problem with this, as you can see in some of the comments to my linked answers. I have yet to see an argument against it ….)